# How to link to a friend in your facebook status update?

Tags: facebook

I want to say in my facebook status update that I heard so-and-so things from my friend "Chuck Turnbull". And I want the text of "Chuck Turnbull" to appear as a link to his profile. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the status update type @ followed by the freinds name and then select them from the list:

[alt text http://cl.ly/1apF/Screen_shot_2010-07-08_at_13.27.36.png](http://cl.ly/1apF/Screen_shot_2010-07-08_at_13.27.36.png)

[alt text http://cl.ly/1aIq/Screen_shot_2010-07-08_at_13.28.36.png](http://cl.ly/1aIq/Screen_shot_2010-07-08_at_13.28.36.png)

Comment: I can't see any images

Answer (score 3):

Just type an `@` as part of your status update followed by your friend's name.  Facebook will prompt you with a list of suggestions and when you click on one the `@` will be removed and a link to your friend will be in its place.